# How to convert strings to int and percentage in dataframe

Tags: python

I have imported this CSV file.

[image]

I am trying to cast the following strings:

- `Avg Spending Hospital` to integer, and
- `Percent Spending Hospital` to percentage.

This is my code:

```
df['Avg Spending Hospital'] = (df['Avg Spending Hospital']).astype(int)
```

My code is throwing an error.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a period at the end of your code?

Comment: also it could help to provide the csv or upload code

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the dollar signs

```
df['Avg Spending Hospital'] = df['Avg Spending Hospital'].str[1:].astype(int)
df['Avg Spending State'] = df['Avg Spending Hospital'].str[1:].astype(int)
df['Avg Spending Nation'] = df['Avg Spending Hospital'].str[1:].astype(int)
```

and the percent signs (the indexes here are [:-1]):

```
df['Percent Spending Hospital'] = df['Percent Spending Hospital'].str[:-1].astype(float)
df['Percent Spending State'] = df['Percent Spending State'].str[:-1].astype(float)
```

Comment: Hi I tried the above code and it is giving me error again. It seems ir is asking to upload python package. Do we have import any pre requisites package for it?Sorry to bother as I am new to python

Comment: could you copy and paste the error?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-2a4dc390079f> in <module>()
     11                 'Percent of Spending (State)':'Percent Spending State',
     12                 'Percent of Spending (Nation)':'Percent Spending Nation'}, inplace=True)
---> 13 df['Avg Spending Hospital'] = df['Avg Spending Hospital'].str[1:].astype(int)
     14 
     15 df

/bda/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2964         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata

Comment: for the percents it should be .str[:-1], not .str[1:]